# How to read Azure application settings from my ASP.NET Core app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-7.0

I went to the Azure portal, and I selected my web app. Under "Application Settings", I selected "New Application Setting" and created a new one there.

This is my code so far:

```
string issueIdentityAPIConfigConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppConfig");
// Load configuration from Azure App Configuration
builder.Configuration.AddAzureAppConfiguration(issueIdentityAPIConfigConnectionString);
builder.Services.Configure<IssueIdentityAPIConfig>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("issueidentityapi:settings"));
```

How do I use the settings once I have the loaded?
I was reading the article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-aspnet-core-app?tabs=core6x, but all the examples in there are for pages, which as far as I can tell automatically take advantage of dependency injection to load the IOptionsSnapshot object. I am writing a REST API, so how do I get at the object?

I should also add that it is only getting past the call the "AddAzureAppConfiguration" locally. The steps in the article only put the connection string named "AppConfig" in local storage. I am ultimately trying to deploy this to Azure, and am still stumped how this is supposed to work up there.

And apologies to people below who got me this far with some of answers. My edits to the original question make it look like I already did something you answered. I blame StackOverflow's ridiculous lack of options in the Comments section preventing a useful back and forth of the actual conversation.

Comment: Post your **actual code**, not a vague description of it.

Comment: I have edited the question and put the code in.

Comment: You need to reference the `Microsoft.Azure.AppConfiguration.AspNetCore` NuGet package (and more), see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-aspnet-core-app?tabs=core6x

Comment: If you added `IssueIdentityDbConnection` to Connection Strings - rather than Application Settings - in the Azure portal, it will be in `configRoot.GetConnectionString("IssueIdentityDbConnection")`.  Items added to Application Settings, e.g. `Setting1`, will be in `configRoot["Setting1"]`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to use dependency injection of the IOptionsSnapshot interface in the constructor for the API controllers. I have this working now on a local deployment. There is a separate issue that remains for getting to work when publishing to Azure which I am going to treat as a different question.

```
   ` public IssueProfilesController (IOptionsSnapshot<IssueIdentityAPIConfig> config)`
```